# Reflection: how to call superclass constructor which is hidden?

Tags: java, android, reflection, superclass

Re-edited...

I'd like to use a superclass constructor which is hidden by the "@hide" Android tag (or whatever it is).

I'm about to extend a class which has been already extended twice (within the Android OS). I'd like to create my own subclass (i.e. outside the Android OS). Example subclass, taken from Android sources:

```
public class WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo extends WifiP2pServiceInfo {
    ...
    private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo(List<String> queryList) {
        super(queryList); // <-- this is what I'm trying to do, too
    }

    public static WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo newInstance(String instanceName,
            String serviceType, Map<String, String> txtMap) {
        ...
        ArrayList<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
        ...
        return new WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo(queries);
    }
}
```

The superclass looks like this:

```
public class WifiP2pServiceInfo implements Parcelable {
    ...
    // this is marked as @hidden therefore inaccessible!
    protected WifiP2pServiceInfo(List<String> queryList) {
        if (queryList == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("query list cannot be null");
        }
        mQueryList = queryList;
    }
}
```

And all I want to do is to make another kind of WifiP2pServiceInfo, similar to the WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo example above. I can't just inherit & call super() because the superclass constructor is tagged by Android's "@hide", therefore unusable without reflection for non-system programmers.

So my question is how to access / call the superclass constructor if I can't do it by a plain super() call? Reflection should come handy here but I'm not very experienced in Java programming.

Comment: if who wrote class A marked the constructor private it means the class is not designed to be extended

Comment: You will already be calling super() in this case. The result of calling two constructors on the same object isn't defined.

Comment: You can define the class in the same package. It doesn't have to be on the same place. I assume that by hidden you mean it has `default` access modifier.

Comment: Is the superclass constructor marked as `protected`?  `private`?  Or nothing (which would make it package-private)?

Comment: @EJP: I'm pretty sure the subclass will not be already calling super()  in this case.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno & others: please see my edited question, I hope it's clearer now. It's really not private, it's just hidden API, as many things in Android are (hotspot comes to my mind).

Comment: @Miro: So you should probably add an android tag to the question. There's no `@Hide` in java

Comment: See my updated answer.  It's very clear that you should not be doing this.

Comment: Saw it and still beg to differ. There are two singletons already (WifiP2pUpnpServiceInfo and WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo), I'd like to create third, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj: thanks, I had no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I'm able to answer the question by myself.

Short answer: I can't do this because if the superclass constructor is protected *and* hidden, the compiler is going to complain even if I found a way how to call the constructor via reflection.

Long answer: it turns out it's not so complicated to "unhide" this stuff. Following [this tutorial](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) I'm able to extend the class to my needs.

See? A lot of noise for nothing, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find that constructor and set its availability to true.

But this is a dangerous operation that you should not attempt lightly.  It's a dirty secret that private need not mean private, but I would still expect you to honor the wishes of the class designer and not circumvent.

Besides, you don't need to.  If I understand your requirement, I've posted an example that will do what you want.

This works, because of this:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

I think you've confused the meaning of the protected modifier.

Parent w/ protected ctor:

```
package foo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Parent with protected constructor
 * User: MDUFFY
 * Date: 3/27/14
 * Time: 5:18 PM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698501/reflection-how-to-call-superclass-constructor-which-is-hidden/22698543?noredirect=1#comment34586243_22698543
 */
public class Foo {
    private List<String> x;

    protected Foo(List<String> y) {
        this.x = ((y == null) ? new ArrayList<String>() : new ArrayList<String>(y));
    }

    public List<String> getX() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.x);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "x=" + x +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Child extends Parent:

```
package bar;

import foo.Foo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Child of parent with protected ctor
 * User: MDUFFY
 * Date: 3/27/14
 * Time: 5:22 PM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698501/reflection-how-to-call-superclass-constructor-which-is-hidden/22698543?noredirect=1#comment34586243_22698543
 */
public class Bar extends Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar(Arrays.asList(args));
        System.out.println(bar);
    }

    public Bar(List<String> y) {
        super(y);
    }


}
```

This will compile and run.

Comment: I'd like to extend one of the Android's classes. The OS already contains two subclasses, I'd like to introduce third, for my own protocol. Therefore I know the signature of the ctors and everything but I'm unable to figure out the correct syntax how to do this (Java newbie here).

Comment: What class?  If it already contains two subclasses, those two subclasses apparently are able to work without using the superclass's private constructor.  So chances are there's a way for you to write another subclass without using it.  ---Unless the constructor is actually package-private (it's not clear from the original question).

Comment: Please see my edited question, I hope it's clearer now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Newbies should not be using reflection in this way.

Comment: I'm a researcher in the Wi-Fi field and I'm not fluent in Java. Despite this heresy I'd like to try out a few things on Android without rooting so reflection is my choice no.1. I'll be extremely happy for any example or advice you can give me (other than "don't do that" :)). Thanks.

Comment: But why you can't just work with an instance of the class? You really need to extend it?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance.  Don't extend a Singleton.  Make your requirements clearer and perhaps we can advise on next steps.

Comment: Right. 10+ years in C++ but sure, I have no clue about OOP only because I haven't been coding in Java, too. I'm NOT trying to extend a Singleton. Please take a closer look. The subclass is the Singleton. I am implementing a Singleton, using normal, non-static, private variables offered by the superclass. So once again, I beg you, if you know an answer, just write it down, it might be useful also for others, it's an interesting (and yet simple) problem to solve.

Comment: Java is not C++, as you well know.  C++ has "friend"; Java has "protected".  I think that's germane here.  The constructor in the superclass is protected: "The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package."   When you say you can't, did you try and fail or do you misunderstand what protected means?  The citation from Oracle docs suggests that it will work.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: WifiP2pServiceInfo (and others) objects are used in Android for various tasks when sending/receiving broadcasts over the air. The superclasses offer some functionality (like parsing incoming/outgoing data) which I'd need to duplicate. That's why I'd like to use its hidden methods, to avoid copy&pasting something which is already implemented and ready to be called ... via reflection :)

Comment: @duffymo: perhaps germane is the fact that Java (as I have learnt just now) doesn't know the "\@hide" thing while Android (Dalvik? Whatever.) does? So while this perhaps would work in Java, in Android I can't access the superclass constructor because it's hidden (by the \@hide "flag" not by the 'protected' access modifier).

Comment: OK, I'm out.  You're on your own.  I posted my best shot.

Comment: @duffymo: maybe I should rephrase the question (sorry, English is not my first language) ... because I see you are tirelessly pointing out to me that protected is accessible from a subclass (this is true for C++, too) but the point here is that Android's \@hide makes this impossible. That's why I'm looking for a solution with reflection (to overcome this). Any help/hints appreciated, really. Reflection is black magic for me.

Comment: Reflection cannot help you.  You have to call super() in the first line of the child constructor, which is impossible with reflection.  You are completely out of luck.

Comment: "The superclasses offer some functionality (like parsing incoming/outgoing data) which I'd need to duplicate." - why must you extend?  If you need that functionality, why can't you simply get it from the superclass and move on?  Still don't see a need to extend.

Comment: @duffymo, you're right about the constructor, I found it out by myself, too. And as to why to extend -- because there's no public superclass constructor.